# How to get action of System Dialong Box programatically

Tags: android, google-glass

I am working on a project where i have to install an app programmatically on **google-glass**, the `intent` leads to a **System Dialog** asking for users permission. Unfortunately the touch pad of the smart glass can not switch between the options. In order to pass them to glass touchpad, or programtically perform their click I need a way to catch the actions of the System Dialog.

Comment: You cannot simulate UI input on system dialogs, except perhaps as an `AccessibilityService`.

Comment: what would you suggest in my case, to go for, where i do not have to root my device,

Comment: Since Google Glass has been discontinued, I have no idea.

Comment: I have to make my app update, from a cloud, storage without user interuption.
my research so far, has been telling me, either i have to root to get system priviliges, to use the permission INSTALL_Packages,  or its the USER who activates the System Action.
I have also looked for EMM solution, but google has made the Device Policy Manger unavailable for the glass.

Comment: yes they are discontinued :(

Comment: @asadnwfp Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @RakeshGopathi
i found that you can do it, after rooting your phone, but I never tried that option.

Comment: @asadnwfp Thanks for the reply. I figured it out and as you rightly pointed out it needs a rooted device to work.